# Parse and Save Javascript Date Objects With Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have hourly date data that comes in the format below, which I need to parse into Javascript date objects, and then save into MongoDB.

Here's my model, specifying the date object:

```
var DateObjectSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
});
```

Here's the format the hourly date data is coming in as:

```
String "01/26/2014 16"
```

Here is what I've tried, but the date is being saved incorrectly:

```
var dateobject = new DateObject({
     date:    new Date("01/26/2014 16" + ":00:00")
});
dateobject.save();
```

For instance, "01/26/2014 24" was being saved into the database as:

```
date: "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

And this "01/26/2014 14" was saved into the database as:

```
date: "2014-01-26T22:00:00.000Z"
```

If it's a timezone issue, please note that I would like all time to be set in **GMT - 7:00**

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to do date manipulations with time zones, it would be worth looking into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and Moment Timezone rather than creating `Date` objects. The Moment interface is higher level and more developer friendly ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date string into date object. Here is one way of doing it from the pattern you specified:

```
var yourInputString = "01/26/2014 16";
var dateHr=yourInputString.split(/\s/); //Gives you the date and hr fields
var date=dateHr[0].split(/\//); //Process the date field by splitting on /
var parsedDate = new Date(date[2],date[0]-1,date[1],dateHr[1]);
```

Now you should be able to use the parsedDate anyway you need.

PS: `date[0]-1` for month field as month is 0 based index.